# DataGridView filtrar y ordenar columnas

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Quisiera poder filtrar y ordenar columnas de un DataGridView, tal como se hace en Excel. Me podrian indicar si esto lo debo hacer por programación, por ejemplo para filtar: Incluir una flecha en el Head de la Columna y ahí poner un evento para poder ordenar en ascendente y descendente.
O existe alguna propiedad del GridView que lo hace más automático.

Los datos los cargo con un DataTable desde Base de Datos.

Comment: Podrías utilizar Jquery DataTables https://datatables.net/

Comment: Se debe hacer mediante programación al momento de hacer tu consulta SQL o al manejador de datos que estés utilizando. Para poner sub nombres a las columas puedes utilizar el AS que es un alias.